# Calling init in init, before self = [super init]

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

It is a common init pattern to do self = [super init]; which should assign the self pointer

But can i forward the init like this?

```
- (id)initWithObject:(id)object {
    return [self initWithObject:object scrollTo:nil];
}
```

The code works, but not sure if it is Kosher... and also how can it work without self = [super init]

moving further, is this ok?

```
- (id)initWithObject:(id)object {
    self = [self initWithObject:object scrollTo:nil]; // NOT super
    if (self) {
       //...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: 100% legitimate. I'm doing this often when I have multiple overloaded constructors

Comment: Yes, but you should really start using `instancetype` rather than `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is fine. I have done this myself a couple of times without problems, and I found a code example in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html) (scroll down to "Multiple Initializers and the Designated Initializer").

Comment: but how is it possible that the self pointer can be accessed, why do we do then self = [super init]

Comment: `self` is already defined because you have already made a call to `[Class alloc]`.

Comment: so why the convention then self = [super init ... ]

Comment: With `alloc`, you only allocate memory for the object. You still have to initialize it - e.g. some initialization code common to all objects is found in the `init` method of `NSObject`.

Comment: but what are the implication on not calling NSObjetcs init, because you can call methods, even when not initialized

Comment: I guess not calling that method is a recipe for memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely legitimate only if in return operator you call designated initializer or initializer which calls the one. Make sure that one way or other the designated initializer is called.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure you can! Note that initWithObject:scrollTo has to return a valid self object.